# Reading .txt file and exporting to .xlsx using pandas(?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a input file as .txt which contains serial numbers and production date alternating between each other.
Example:
SERIALNUMBER1

PRODUCTIONDATE1

SERIALNUMBER2

PRODUCTIONDATE2

Now I want to create to Headers with pandas using this block of code:

```
def read_txt_export_to_excel():
    dataframe_test_raw = pd.read_table("serialnumbers.txt", delimiter=" ")
    dataframe_test_raw.columns = ["ProductionDate", "Time", "Serialnumber"]
    dataframe_test_raw.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

So far, so good. I just dont understand how I can make pandas to read all serialnumbers which have a prefix so its easy to find and place them for example under "Serialnumber" in the .xlsx.

Every serialnumber begins with "X87"

My guess is to start like that:

```
with open('serialnumbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
        for line in f:
```

And now I have kind of a blockade. I want to scan the serialnumbers.txt with the "for" loop and pass it to pandas.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks guys!

EDIT SERIALNUMBERS.txt
http://pastie.org/p/4WADkzaLVL5Tsijgh5SyGc

**What I need:**
I want the Serialnumbers to appear in the excel file with the column name "Serialnumbers"
I also want the Production date (which is always under the serialnumber) next to it in the excel with the column name "Production Date".

What I have to far thanks to @It_is_chris:

```
def read_txt_export_to_excel():
    # Production data read-in
    df = pd.read_table("Serialnumbers.txt", delimiter=" ")
    print(df.columns)

    # filter every other row using .iloc and concat
    data = pd.concat([df[ProductionDate].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True),
                  df[SerialNumber].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

    # assign column names
    data.columns = ['ProductionDate', 'SerialNumber']
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am in talks with user @It_is_chris but I will clarify the question further now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date and serial number just alternate every row then do

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(['SERIALNUMBER1', 'PRODUCTIONDATE1',
                   'SERIALNUMBER2', 'PRODUCTIONDATE2'])

# filter every other row using .iloc and concat
data = pd.concat([df[0].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True),
                  df[0].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

# assign column names
data.columns = ['ProductionDate', 'SerialNumber']


    ProductionDate   SerialNumber
0  PRODUCTIONDATE1  SERIALNUMBER1
1  PRODUCTIONDATE2  SERIALNUMBER2
```

Here is an updated solution

```
df = pd.read_csv('serialnumbers.txt', header=None, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# filter every other row using .iloc and concat
data = pd.concat([df[0].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True),
                  df[0].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

# rename columns
data.columns = ['ProductionDate', 'Serialnumber']

# convert date column to datetime
data['ProductionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ProductionDate'])
# create a new time column
data['Time'] = data['ProductionDate'].dt.time
# remove the time from the date . . . if you want
data['ProductionDate'] = data['ProductionDate'].dt.date
print(data)

  ProductionDate        Serialnumber      Time
0     2022-07-06  X87YAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  06:43:00
1     2022-07-06  X87YBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  06:51:00
2     2022-07-06  X87YCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  06:53:00
3     2022-07-06  X87YDDDDDDDDDDDDDD  06:54:00
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the problem that the serialnumbers done are different each day so I just need  like sometimes 50 numbers sometimes 200. Do I need to add all of them to the dataframe?

Comment: Also now if I want to let pandas read my .txt via pd.read_table() it errors out.

Comment: @SabriLK you would just read the data as normal: `df = pd.read_table("serialnumbers.txt", delimiter=" ")` then do `data = pd.concat([df[0].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True), df[0].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)` you would replace `df[0]` with whatever the column name is.

Comment: thanks now I changed everything correctly and now my code looks like that. Now I am getting a really really weird error from pandas..
`def read_txt_export_to_excel():
    # Production data read-in
    df = pd.read_table("VINs.txt", delimiter=" ")

    # filter every other row using .iloc and concat
    data = pd.concat([df[0].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True),
                  df[0].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

    # assign column names
    data.columns = ['ProductionDate', 'SerialNumber']
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx")`

Comment: sorry I am super new to pandas and it really drives me crazy :D
The error I am getting now is this:
https://ibb.co/YNQyWjQ

Comment: @SabriLK please join this chat. It will be a little easier to help there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246202/sabrilk

Comment: It really looks like a pandas error? Or is there something wrong with my code? I checked it 2 times and I dont think so...(?)

Comment: I cant join the chat as I need 20 reputation? Maybe some other chat? I really dont get it why I need 20 rep for that.

Comment: That is OK. The key error means that `df[0]` is not the column name. Do `print(df.columns)` and use that columns name instead of `0` so it will be `df['some_col_name']` rather than `df[0]`

Comment: I assume I need to swap the 0 to one of those? data.columns = ['ProductionDate', 'SerialNumber'] But I get the error that the names are not defined?

Comment: @SabriLK can you add the first few rows of your txt file to the question and redact the serial numbers...I do not need to seem them?

Comment: Done. Its in the pastie.org link

Comment: @SabriLK see updated solution

Comment: OMG I WAS STUPID. I need to export data and not df to ecxel! Now it works perfectly! Thank you soooo sooo much!!!

Comment: @SabriLK you're welcome and good luck.